# The ability to fight with Ad-Blocker

Tags: php, html

I had searched by google and this forum-search and I didnt get any about this so I propose a new topic: WordPress with the ability to fight with Ad-Blocker.

I am not an IT guy (subsea engineer) but I am having [website](http://interresults2015.in/) with about 100 - 200 unique visitor/day now (according to adsense) as hobby (1%-4% using ad-blocker - I am lucky to have these ~97% my visitors).

I just learn that ad-block users are about 300 mil and it is a huge problem to big publisher (they earn money from ads). Ad-blocker using bandwith, upload data to their server and some (one of them - I expect more of them) sell the data as anons.

In accordance to the above idea,
I have a question as a-non IT guys, is there a way to make WordPress to tackle ad-blocker (auto)?

It may be a way to disarm ad-blocker. My website is like my home/house. You/Visitors can visit but please consider the owner.

Comment: Not really related to what you're asking, but the reason so many use adblock is annoying ads, such that moves alot and specially pop-ups, they interfere with their user experience of that website. Please avoid those ads. A little on dealing with adblock; it's not possible to my knowledge to disable it, but you can detect it, and display a message "we notice you're using adblock. To maintain this website, we rely on income from ads" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No from what I can tell, it keeps a list of servers which are used to serve advertisements. Whenever you visit any website, the web browser has to fetch the components from the various servers. Adblock simply blocks the connections to any item on its list of ad servers, thus blocking all or most ads. The list of servers has to be updated ever so often which it does in the backend.